# Find emails by message Id using using IMAP and MailSystem.NET

Tags: c#, imap, mailsystem.net

I'm using IMAP and MailSystem.NET to read emails in c#. How do I search emails by message id? (msg.MessageId)

```
 using (Imap4Client imap = new Imap4Client()){
        imap.ConnectSsl(protocol, port);
        imap.LoginFast(email, password);

        Mailbox inbox = imap.SelectMailbox("INBOX");

        int[] mails= inbox.Search("UNSEEN");

        for (int i = 0; i < mailsUnread.Length; i++) {
            Message msg = inbox.Fetch.MessageObject(mailsUnread[i]);
            string subject = msg.Subject;
           string body = msg.BodyText.Text;

           string messageId= msg.MessageId; 

         }
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) instead as it is a much much much more robust IMAP client library than MailSystem.NET... but...

The way you would search for messages based on the Message-Id header in MailSystem.NET is:

```
int[] mails = inbox.Search (string.Format ("HEADER \"MESSAGE-ID\" \"{0}\"", msg.MessageId));
```

Hope that helps.